# Intersections of translations of subgroups of the integers

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $(\tau_j, g_j)_{j \in \mathrm{F}}$ be a *finite* family of pairs of integers. Let $\mathrm{G}_j = \tau_j + \langle g_j \rangle$ be the translation by $\tau_j$ of the subgroup of $\mathbf{Z}$ generated by $g_j.$

> What possible cardinalities can there by for a subset $\mathrm{H}$ of $\mathrm{F}$ such that $\bigcap\limits_{j \in \mathrm{H}} \mathrm{G}_j$ is not empty?

As a context, this problem appeared somewhat lightweight in a high-school homework. There the situation was that racers were going to start with different advantages (2, 3, 7) and they had different running speeds (18, 15, 13) and if they were going to be at the same spot (assuming they run indefinitely). I am curious in the more general form expressed above.